# If item has field then display field Django

Tags: python, django

So i made a model where putting in a picture is optional ... Now what I'm trying to do is display ALL posts as part of the home screen including ones that don't have an image (where the user left the image blank) How do I go about doing this? If anyone could help that would be great!! Thanks! This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
{% for post in posts.all %}

    <a href="{% url 'postDetail' post.id%}"><h3>{{post.title}}</h3></a>
    <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{post.pubDatePretty}}</h4>
    <br />
    {% if POST HAS IMAGE %}
        <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="img-responsive center-block" style = "max-height:150px;"/>
    {% endif %}
    <br />
    <p>{{post.summary}}</p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
{% endfor %}
```

Model Page:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def pubDatePretty(self):
        return self.pubDate.strftime('%b %e %Y')

    def summary(self):
        return self.body[0:100]
```

Answer (score 4):

`None` counts as `False` in a boolean context, so just `{% if post.image %}` should work fine.